# Installation of archived package "prob" not working in R

Tags: r

I'm running R 3.4.2 and R Studio 1.0.153. I want to install the `prob` package in R. The `prob` package in an archived file. It is located [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/prob/). I am trying to install the prob_1.0-0.tar.gz package. I have no problem downloading and opening the package archive file. The code is below, it seems I need to install the `fAsianOptions` package.

> ERROR: dependency 'fAsianOptions' is not available for package 'prob'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/blake_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/prob' Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "C:\Users\blake_000\Documents\R\win-library\3.4"
>   "C:/Users/BLAKE_~1/GOOGLE~1/Life/CSUEB/FALL20~1/6204-P~1/RCODE~1/prob_1.0-0.tar.gz"'
>   had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘C:/Users/BLAKE_~1/GOOGLE~1/Life/CSUEB/FALL20~1/6204-P~1/RCODE~1/prob_1.0-0.tar.gz’
>   had non-zero exit status

Unfortunately, the `fAsianOptions` package is also archived. It is located [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fAsianOptions/) and I downloaded version fAsianOptions_3010.79.tar.gz. There were a number of dependencies but I installed the required packages (`timeDate`, `timeSeries`, etc.)

However, the `fAsianOptions` package is not installing. The error code reads as follows:

> install.packages("C:/Users/blake_000/Google Drive/Life/CSUEB/Fall
>   2017/6204- Probability/R Code/fAsianOptions_3010.79.tar.gz", repos =
>   NULL, type = "source") Installing package into
>   ‘C:/Users/blake_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified)
>   * installing *source* package 'fAsianOptions' ...
>   ** package 'fAsianOptions' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386 Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk"
>   SHLIB="fAsianOptions.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)'
>   OBJECTS="EBMAsianOptions.o GammaFunctions.o
>   HypergeometricFunctions.o"' had status 127 ERROR: compilation failed
>   for package 'fAsianOptions'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/blake_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/fAsianOptions' Warning
>   in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "C:\Users\blake_000\Documents\R\win-library\3.4"
>   "C:/Users/BLAKE_~1/GOOGLE~1/Life/CSUEB/FALL20~1/6204-P~1/RCODE~1/fAsianOptions_3010.79.tar.gz"'
>   had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘C:/Users/BLAKE_~1/GOOGLE~1/Life/CSUEB/FALL20~1/6204-P~1/RCODE~1/fAsianOptions_3010.79.tar.gz’
>   had non-zero exit status

I'm hoping that someone can help me to install the `fAsianOptions` dependency so I can install the prob package. Or, if there's an easier way, please let me know!

Comment: Packages are removed from CRAN precisely for the reason that they no longer work with current versions of R. You should probably seek an alternative to the `prob` package. You use packages deleted from CRAN at your own risk. What is it exactly that you think you need the `prob` package for? Maybe that would be a better question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by installing lower version of `R` -2.9. `prob` is available in repository for this version.

Answer (score 0):

go to this site and download the prob package from this link, don't download the latest version of prob try 2008 version.

> https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/prob/

now open your RStudio and install this package manually,
for updated RStudio-

1. Click on the Tools option,
2. Click on Install Package,
3. Select Package Archive
   [image]

4. select Package file and click install

hope it will work.